# Tracking the Reseller of the iPhone -App from inside the App

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I have been stuck in a strange situation, according to my requirement, I need to track the resellers of my app, i.e. I will be publishing link of my app in the iTunes-Store on 3 or more different sites(The re seller's sites).
According to my promise which I made to these resellers, I will provide a share of my profit.
So here I have to track from which link did the user came to the APP-Store.

Any suggestions or solutions will be Thankful.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to do it will be server-side. Links at your resellers should point to your server, where you log the source of link (resellers web page) and redirect request to AppStore. But you'll have no way of knowing, which of this requests ended up with a purchase.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this for real is to get them to become iTunes affiliates and provide reports back to you.  They should use the iTunes referral to make the sale (they will get a small cut from Apple) -- Apple will report that back to them, and then they can prove to you that they made a sale, and then you pay based on that.

Reserve the right to audit them -- meaning that they will have to show you the report directly from the iTunes affiliate site.

I assume that iTunes actually tells them what they sold, but you would need to check that.

Comment: Thanks, Do u have Any link or documentation regarding this approach where I can learn about the same...
Thanks IN Advance..

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=itunes+affiliate&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Another idea (which may or may not make sense based on what your app does) is to make personalized versions of your app for each reseller.  If there's some way to incorporate a very simple feature that is personalized (and makes sense), then you can upload the same app multiple times and assume all sales are coming from that reseller.

So, for example, if the app were an exercise tracker, and the resellers were gyms -- you could customize the app for each gym and add their schedule and contact info to it.  Then, sell the app as an Excerise Tracker for XYZ Gym and let them promote it and get a cut of sales.